# Get src of img element from div?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the src of the img element in HTML. It looks like this:

```
<div class="image_wrapper" id="this_one">
        <img src="Images/something.jpg" />
</div>
```

It's very simple when I put an ID in img, and get this src very easy.

But the problem is when I get src of img from div element.

```
var someimage = document.getElementById('this_one').firstChild.getAttribute("src");
alert(someimage);
```

I need to get this URL in string. But not worth.

Comment: What you get in _someimage_ ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Why not try something like this:

```
var someimage = document.getElementById('this_one');
var myimg = someimage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var mysrc = myimg.src;
```

For more on using getElementsByTagName you may want to look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

There is some error checking I didn't do here, but I am just trying to show how you can do it.

Answer (score 5):

Or even simpler :

```
document.getElementById('yourimageID').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src
```

Works for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the space characters between the `div` and `img` tags. That is why the first element of the div is not the image but the text - which has no method **getAttribute**.

You can remove spaces and use your js as it was:

```
<div class="image_wrapper" id="this_one"><img src="Images/something.jpg" /></div>
```

it will be working:

```
var someimage = document.getElementById('this_one').firstChild.getAttribute("src");
alert(someimage);
```

---

You can get the image tag from your's div using `getElementsByTagName('img')` as following:

```
var divEl = document.getElementById('this_one'),
    src = divEl.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

The above will solve your task.

More you can get from here [Scripting Documents](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=4RChxt67lvwC&lpg=PP1&dq=javascript%20the%20definitive%20guide&pg=PA361), I advise you to read this chapter.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is asked for js which has been answered, for jquery

```
var image = $('#this_one img')[0];       // $('#this_one img') this will return the img array. In order to get the first item use [0]
var imageSrc = image.src;
alert(imageSrc);
```

It might be useful for someone who looks similarly in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of using `element.firstChild` , use `element.children[0]` . Also, instead of `element.getAttribute('src')` , use `element.src` .

Hope this helps,

Awesomeness01

Answer (score 1):

Why do we need to use jQuery if we can get the img src within the document by `querySelector`?

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('[src*="Images/something.jpg"]')
```

P.S.: jQuery has 94 kb minified file size. Please don't include it unless there's a requirement.